# How can I execute LITERALLY this?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to execute a valid command on MySQL on my C# code. I tried on SQL section in phpmyadmin and it works, but now, I must execute it on my C# program and I don't have any idea how to do it

C# suppose this @ refers to a parameter and it expects it, but it isn't, what I want is execute this command as it is.
I tried to asign it as a parameter like ("@TRIGGER_CHECKS","@TRIGGER_CHECKS") but it doesn't work either.

This is the command, it works on MySQL:

```sql
SET @TRIGGER_CHECKS = TRUE;
```

I want to execute that command on C# and I don't know how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you write a stored procedure that does that command and call the procedure instead?

Comment: I'm trying and it doesn't work in a procedure, only if i execute it isolated.

Comment: You could try `string query = @"SET @TRIGGER_CHECKS = TRUE;"` see here the explainment about [@](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: @RaymondNijland `@` is not a special character at the C# level. `@"@"` and `"@"` are identical.

Comment: *"@ is not a special character at the C# level. @"@" and "@" are identical."* @GSerg mine comment was fore meant because ive read *"C# suppose this @ refers to a parameter and it expects it"* But you could be right i didn't do C# for a while now so iam a bit rusty.

Comment: @RaymondNijland The `MySqlCommand` [understands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) the `@TRIGGER_CHECKS` as a parameter named `TRIGGER_CHECKS`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the link @GSerg then mine mind is blown why the MySQL devs would choose the `@` for a param then with makes it incompatible with MySQL user variable not really smart..

Comment: @RaymondNijland the MSSQL provider has the same issue. Major bummer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Connector/NET assumes that any variable prefixed with a `@` is a parameter to the SQL statement.

To allow your statement to execute correctly, you need to add [`;Allow User Variables=true`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-6-10-connection-options.html) to your connection string. Then the command will be passed to the server as-is.